# Sliding an edge loop in an imported image distorts the image (blender 2.81)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Using the loop cut in older versions, we could make a loop cut and slide it in one action before committing. Now one has to set the loop cut, then with edge slide, move the edge.
This doesn't work when one uses an 'import image as plane', since when you move the edge it distorts the image on the plane. The old way allowed one to make the loop cut and move it in one action before setting it- thus no distortion.

Is there another way to do loop cut-slide in 2.81 on images that I haven't seen yet?

Answer (score 1):

In the tool menu for Loop Cut and Slide (after making a loop cut once), check 'Correct UVs' and it should work as you expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable *Correct UVs* option, when creating the loopcut.
It is located in the pop-up menu.
Once enabled, it stays that way.

This works for *Loopcuts*, *Edge slides* and other tools.

[image]

By the way - you can still slide Loop cuts before committing.
No need to use Edge slide tool.

Comment: This was the same in 2.7x.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll edit my answer :)